# Drive missing & Failed after firware upgrade

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hp-proliant

I have a drive which was working before and after we upgraded the system and firmware the disk shows "Unknown" & "Failed". We have a windows server 2012R2.

We see the device drivers are all upto date and have multiple times tried to remove and insert the drive.

The server is HP Proliant 380 Gen 10 server

[image]

Any help on how we could fix this would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firmware upgrade for what device?

Comment: @Moab we did a windows system update